# Rounding up the time expression in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data `Y` . `Y` has a column `time` .
`time`  column looks like this:

[image]

For example, `20211201000010` means `2021-12-01 00:00:10` .

`time <- strptime(Y$time, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`

`start_time <- min(time)`

In this code, `start_time` is `2021-12-01 00:00:02`.

But I want to round up the `start_time`as `2021-12-01 00:00:10`,since the `start_time` should be 10 seconds interval for my data.

How can I round up `2021-12-01 00:00:02` as `2021-12-01 00:00:10` ?

Comment: Okay. I will not include irrelevant tag next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lubridate` package is always our friends for datetime work.

---

```
library(lubridate)      
xx1 <- '20211201010002'

ymd_hms(xx1) %>%
  ceiling_date(unit = '10s')
```

---

```
[1] "2021-12-01 01:00:10 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to calculate the remainder (divide by 10) before you format the data.

e.g.

```
20211201000002 %% 10 = 2;
20211201000010 %% 10 = 0
```

Then you find the first 0 in your list.